# LocalDate as where clause in Intellij's JPA Console

Tags: intellij-idea

Let's say I have a Person with a name and a birth date. Entity model is as follow :

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    // constructors, getters and setters...
}
```

With the JPA Console, I would like to write a query like this :

```java
@Query("select p from Person p where p.birthDate between :start and :stop")
List<Person> getPeopleBornBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate stop);
```

If I try the query as it is and write the date between `'` , parameters do not match expected type.
I cannot use Local.parse(...) in the parameters popup window neither in the console.
I also cannot use p.birthDate.format(...) in the console.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem in you query, try this one:

```sql
select p from Person p where p.birthDate between :start and :stop
                     ^
```

Comment: this is only a typo I made while working this query on SO. I will edit this. My issue is how to do this query in the JPA Console, not in my java source code.